# Replacing scp with rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp, file-copy

For a long time I've been wishing to replace `scp` in favor of `rsync` due to all the advantages and extra features of the latter (better performance, resuming interrupted downloads, displaying progress etc).

However I'm still stuck with `scp`: I'm too lazy to choose which options to use with `rsync`. Every time I need a specific feature (e.g. resuming an interrupted download) it takes minutes to research how to do it. Add to it the fact that `rsync` with no options has disadvantages over `scp` (e.g. it's less secure, if you don't use `--rsh=ssh`) and `scp` is just the laziest choice.

I'd like to pick a set of options once and for all, set up a good `rscp` alias and live happily ever after.

Can someone recommend a good set of options to use `rsync` to copy files over `ssh`?

Comment: 1. If I understand correctly,`--rsh=ssh` is the default for `rsync`. 2. If you want all permissions and ownership to be preserved, you can use `sudo -avn source/ target`. If you want to preserve hard links too, use `sudo -Havn source/ target`; There may be problems with some ownership and permissions without sudo (or without running as root), but you may not be able to do that at the remote side of the connection (at the ssh server).

Answer (score 2):

## Aliasing

We can alias the best rsync configurations adding the following in your shell configuration file (be sure to add `comunque` to your $PATH if you are going to use it as shown):

```bsh
~/.zshrc     (or ~/.bashrc)
-----------------------

rsync          = alias comunque "rsync -Phav {} {}"

rsync_no_links = alias comunque "rsync -rptgoDLK {} {}"

rsync_remote   = alias comunque "rsync -Phavz {} {}"
```

Make the shell see the new configuration:

```bsh
source ~/.zshrc             # or .bashrc or whatever
```

#### Run

Now you can run your shiny new aliases as normal programs:

```
rsync source destination
rsync_no_links source destination
rsync_remote really_remote_source destination
```

#### Sources

- [*Comunque*](https://github.com/tallero/misc/blob/master/comunque), for easy bash aliasing.

Comment: Compression is really only useful over _really_ slow connections (must be slower or much slower than the compression bandwidth), and there's a caveat with using a source that does/doesn't end with a `/`.

Comment: This works, but doesn't enable many of the nice features of `rsync`... I was thinking about including `--progress`, `--human-readable`, something to resume interrupted downloads etc, in order to not having to look up how to achieve these things when I need them.

Comment: Why not just use ordinary shell functions?

Comment: Because I do not like their syntax, so I try to avoid them whenever I can. Since these days Python is included in almost all setups, I've come to start advicing `alias` + `comunque` (tool to run shell commands with Python-like replacement syntax) instead of shell functions (in feasible situations) because of their extremely light syntax.